# Clamav-Daemon Can't Open lmd.user.ndb, won't start

Tags: 14.04, clamav

Can't start clamav-daemon, and searching for help on the error has turned up nothing.

```
 * Starting ClamAV daemon clamd
LibClamAV Error: cli_load(): Can't open file /var/lib/clamav/lmd.user.ndb
LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): error loading database /var/lib/clamav/lmd.user.ndb
ERROR: Can't open file or directory
Closing the main socket.
```

`lmd.user.ndb` is linked to: `/usr/local/maldetect/sigs/lmd.user.ndb`

Which is in turn linked to: `/usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.runtime.user.4696.hdb`, which is a file that doesn't exist.

At the moment my email server isn't working, so I'm really stuck. Any ideas folks?

Running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same problem here on Ubuntu 12.04.
If you disable maldet temporary by:

`mv /usr/local/maldetect /usr/local/maldetect.DISABLE`

clamav-daemon can be started error free again.
and mail will start working again.

This is a work around of course and I am still investigating what is the real problem.

anton

update:
after updating maldet from 1.4.2 to maldet 1.5  the problem was solved here.

Answer (score 2):

As Update from Anton says, updating maldet was the answer for me too. But I had to force it, since maldet was supposed to be already updated to version 1.5:

`wget http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz
tar -xzvf maldetect-current.tar.gz
cd maldetect-1.5
./install.sh`

After that, the problem was solved. Thanks Anton for the hint.

PS. System here is Debian 7.

Comment: This should be an edit to the original answer instead of a new answer.  **;-)**